# Unexpected result using very simple regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing this simple regexp in Javascript

```
str = "1-2-3-456789";
re = /(\d+)/;
found = str.match(re);
alert(found);
```

I'm waiting for an array with 1,2,3,456789 but the result is 1,1
Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `g` (global) flag to your pattern.

```
re = /(\d+)/g;
```

Otherwise it would stop at the first match, in which case the return would be 1 (for the whole match), 1 (the control group).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you start making mistakes like these, it's time to hit the bed.